# Qt как узнать цвет пикселя

Tags: c++, qt

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::red,Qt::SolidPattern));  
    painter.drawRect(10,10,100,100);
}
```

Имея данный код как узнать цвет пикселя (20,20)?

В интернете нашел такой способ, но он не работает

```
QPixmap qPix = QPixmap::grabWidget(ui->centralWidget);
        QImage image(qPix.toImage());
        QColor color(image.pixel(20, 20));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вроде этого:

```
QColor QMainWindow::getPixelAt(int x, int y)
{
    return grab(QRect(x, y, 1, 1)).toImage().pixelColor(0,0);
}
```

Но этот код нельзя вызывать непосредственно из MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e), так как использование метода grab приводит к вызову этого самого paintEvent, и возникнет бесконечная рекурсия. Так что получается ерунда. Если вам нужно знать состояние целевого пикселя во время прорисовки, ИМХО лучше иметь промежуточный буфер и работать с ним, а потом уже его конечное состояние рисовать на виджет.